# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'subs'

Tags: filtering, django-queryset

Can someone pls explain how can I filter users posts if user is subscriber or not?

'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'subs'

I use custom user

```
class Every(AbstractBaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Here is post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=1200)
```

A subscriber model:

```
class Sub(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    subs = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='subs')
```

A view that I'm trying to use:

```
def tape(request, every_id):
    context = {}
    context.update(csrf(request))
    post_form = PostForm
    pform = post_form
    sub = Sub.objects.filter(subs=every_id)# here I get users that intersting for my user
    tape = Post.objects.filter(user=sub.subs).order_by("-timestamp")
    username = request.user
    context = {"username": username, "pform": pform, "tape": tape, "sub": sub,}
    return render(request, 'tape.html', context)
```

Comment: what is this `every_id `?

Comment: every_id is id of an additional model for user. 
```class Every(AbstractBaseUser):```
here i can add addresses, hobbies, name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it would be better to use a class view. But here is an answer with an usual view. We need to get subscription's and subscribers's ids before we start filter posts

here is even a bit more :-)

```
def get_user_id_list(user):
    """Returns a list of subscribers's ids"""
    try:
       sub = user.user
    Sub.DoesNotExist:
       return []
    return sub.subs.all().values_list('user_id', flat=True)


def get_user_id_list_2(user):
     """Returns a list of subscription's ids"""
     return user.subs.values_list('user_id', flat=True)


def tape(request):
    pform = PostForm
    user_id_list = get_user_id_list_2(request.user)
    logger.info('user_id_list = {}'.format(user_id_list))
    tape = Post.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_id_list).order_by("-timestamp")
    username = request.user
    context = {
        "username": username,
        "pform": pform,
        "tape": tape,
        "sub": sub,
    }
    return render(request, 'tape.html', context)
```